# Change XAMPP RAM, CPU settings

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, optimization, amazon-ec2, xampp

This might seem like a silly question to some but I'm new to the world of XAMPP & web development so here goes. I am developing a Java Web Application and deploying it on XAMPP using a WAR file. The hardware specs of my development machine are:-

1. 4 GB RAM
2. Intel CORE 2 DUO processor
3. Windows 7(64 bit)

When I run the application on my local dev machine it works fine but when I deploy the code to my Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance that's where the problem starts. The application becomes very slow.

The hardware specs of EC2 t2.micro instance are given is this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Since I cannot upgrade my t2.micro EC2 instance due to budget constraints, is there a way I could change the XAMPP settings so that the RAM, CPU available to my application is reduced. This will help me to catch performance issue before hand and optimize my code accordingly.. Please help

Comment: Your development machine will have different bottlenecks even if you reduce RAM, CPU; reducing them could help, but just as likely won't help at all since you won't be able to replicate the exact network latency or any other of a dozen criteria.  If you have performance problems, you're better off gathering as much information as you can about your application's behavior so you can identify the real bottlenecks, such as whether it needs over 1GiB memory and pages memory to disk on XAMPP.  This perf info will be more useful overall, e.g. if you run into additional performance problems later.

Comment: @MattJordan Thanks for the information..any idea how to collect application behaviour information??

Comment: I'd start with Performance Monitor (normally at c:\windows\system32\perfmon.exe), which allows you to watch the real-time resource activity of a single application rather than the whole computer - it isn't a simple monitor, but it is worth knowing!  after that, additional investigation would be based on what perfmon says.  Since this is a web application, you will most likely have to watch the web server instance as well as the java instance (if it is visible), but on a development machine you shouldn't have any other web applications that might take up non-trivial amounts of resources.